# How to combine auto getter&setter with PIMPL design pattern in a public API interface class

Tags: c++, design-patterns

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Note: Automatically generate getter and setter
template<typename T>
class Wrap {
public:
  ...
  const T& operator()() const 
  { 
    return m_element; 
  }

  void operator()(const T& element)
  {
    m_element = element;
  }
  ...

private:
  T m_element;
};

// Pro:  The container may have more than 20 different member variables.
//       Each goes with a simple getter and setter for now. Due to the Wrap
//       class, we don't have to add getter and setter for any new variable
// Con:  Since this is a public API interface, if the user directly adopt the
//       Wrap class, it is difficult for any future improvement. Based on this design,
//       we cannot make Wrap private embeded class of Container since the user needs to 
//       access those public member variables of Container
class Container
{
public:
  Wrap<int>         Age;
  Wrap<double>      Balance;
  ...
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Con: For each different member variable, we have to add getter and setter methods
//       which will be a problem considering if you have 20 member variables.
// Pro:
//       By using PIMPL pattern, we can make the interface more robust for future improvement
//       without breaking our client's code.
class PimplClass
{
public:
    int Age() const;
    PimplClass& Age(int _age);

    double Balance() const;
    PimplClass& Balance(double _balance);

private:
    Pimpl* m_data; // hide internal data structure from the public API interface
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

**Question**> Is there a better design that I can combine both auto getter+setter generation and PIMPL design pattern
into this public API interface?

Thank you

// ************** Updated ************************

After reading all those articles, I am convinced that getter and setter are evil. Now the question comes to how to avoid them all together.

For example,

```
class Bond
{
    ...

private:
    long m_lPrice;
    std::string m_strBondName;
    int  m_iVolume;
}
```

Give the above class `Bond` which includes three member variables, without using getter and setter, how does client get the price, name, or volume of an bond object?

This is the another example of getter/setter in Qt4.

Here's the improved QProgressBar API:

```
class QProgressBar : public QWidget
{
    ...
public:
    void setMinimum(int minimum);
    int minimum() const;
    void setMaximum(int maximum);
    int maximum() const;
    void setRange(int minimum, int maximum);
    int value() const;

    virtual QString text() const;
    void setTextVisible(bool visible);
    bool isTextVisible() const;
    Qt::Alignment alignment() const;
    void setAlignment(Qt::Alignment alignment);

public slots:
    void reset();
    void setValue(int value);

signals:
    void valueChanged(int value);
    ...
};
```

Thank you

Comment: You know that Wrap thingy is completely useless?

Comment: This is *incredibly pointless*, you know.

Comment: Setters and getters are evil. Time to post [that link](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf) [PDF] again.

Comment: @sbi - I disagree.  *Stupid* setters and getters are evil.  Setters and getters that enforce some sort of runtime access policy are in fact good, as are setters and getters that perform some sort of transformation (such as obtaining a pointer to a base of the contained object).

Comment: @MichaelPrice: In almost two decades I have come across very few getters and setters that were _not_ stupid.

Comment: @sbi: good article, but what is the solution for quasi-classes?

Comment: @q0987: I can't do this in a comment, I will try to write an answer instead.

Answer (score 8):

Getters and setters are there so that you can "grab" into an object's guts and fiddle with its innards. That should make your alarm bells ring very loudly. For a ***well-designed class***, you do not have to dig through its guts, since it lets you do everything you need to do ***through its interface*** ***without leaking any of its implementation details*** through the abstraction.

Design a class ***from the point of view*** of a ***user*** of the class (*"if I have a `qrxl` object, I would need to make it `wrgl()` like this, and I also need to pass it a `lrxl` object occasionally, which it then uses to do `frgl()`"*), rather than from the point of view of the *implementer* who needs to somehow organize his data and algorithms into useful (for him!) chunks. (*"Let's just put this Johnny over here into that class, because that's where it is close to where I need it for implementing the `xrxl()` algorithm."*)

I think in this regard ***Java has done a huge disservice*** to humanity in that it ***requires*** you to put everything into some class, even if this is against how you actually visualize your design in your head, and even if you are not (yet) thinking object-oriented. This seems to have made a design style en vogue where programmers just stuff everything into some class somewhere because "that's the way it's done."
In lots of Java code I've seen the underlying programming style is actually *Structured Programming* (basically "collect your data in useful chunks, and pass those to your algorithms", as done in C or Pascal), rather than *Object-oriented Programming*. Just because you replace `struct`/`record` by `class` and make the data members in this chunk only accessible through getters and setters, this doesn't mean you are doing object-oriented programming.<sup>1</sup> This is what the author of [that wonderful short paper](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf) calls ***pseudo classes***

From what little I know about Qt, its design is also a pretty good example for a pretty bad example, with everything allocated on the heap, handed around in naked pointers, and employing the quasi-class school of design.

---

> Give the above class `Bond` which includes three member variables, without using getter and setter, how does client get the price, name, or volume of an bond object?

This is ***the wrong question***. The right question is ***why would a user need to get at those values?*** If you need to get at them manually, then `Bond` isn't high enough an abstraction for OO design, it's a mere C-style `struct` where you throw together all the data you need in one place. Ask yourself:

***What would a user of a `Bond` want to do with such an object?*** How can I make the class support those operations without users having to grab into it and fiddle with its guts? How can I make the classes that interact with `Bond` do this? Can I pass them `Bond` objects, rather than price, name, or volume of an bond object?

Yes, sometimes you have to have just a bond's price in order to display it, and if that's the case, then `Bond` will need to support a getter function for the price, and that's Ok then. But you could still pass a `Bond` object to your `BondPriceTable`'s `displayBonds()` function, and let that decide whether it wants to just grab the name and the price and throw that at the screen or display more values. There is no need to extract name and price manually and pass those to a `display()` function.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sup><sub>That's especially appalling because Java aficionados so often look down at C++ for not being "purely OO".</sub></sup>

Comment: Qt does not force the programmer to allocate on the heap and it provides various smart pointer classes. Also, any QObject can be put into an allocation graph, providing a semi-automatic memory management scheme.

Comment: @TamásSzelei: As I said, I know very little about Qt, but I think its API is all naked pointers. ICBWT.

Comment: Then it's perhaps not a good idea to bring it up as an example. All Qt API functions that return or take pointers employ the QObject graph.

Comment: In general "pseudo classes"  attack is justified. But what happens when this simple structure requires a "compilation firewall" (PIMPL)? it seems that this aspect is muted in every "setters/getters are evil" posts. I actually face this problem in the products I develop. This simple struct is used in external libraries, which requires backward portability.

Comment: @chook: Pimpl is all about how you hold data — directly or through a reference. What's that got to do with whether users of a class should access a class' privates?

Comment: @sbi using Pimpl for simple container (c_struct), result in a "pseudo class". How can it be avoided? The only needed from this struct is read/write access to contained data.

Comment: @chook: You call it a struct, and the only thing you need it to do is to let you at its innards. Well, I guess then it is not a class and not OO. What do you want me to do about this? All I can do is questioning your motivation for doing this.

Comment: @sbi motivation - the struct is located in a lower library. it's symbol is external to client libraries (not mine), and it needs backward compatibility. It requires access e.g. for serialization (e.g. JSON), and other purposes but I hope the point is clear

Comment: @chook: Ah, but a struct that assembles a bunch of (related) data is not OO. Which is my original point. _Note:_ There is valid reasons to decide against OO. (There is, after all, even valid reasons to decide for assembler.) But if your types are record-like, with public data (whether accessed directly or through getters/setters), then these aren't OO-like class types, and you're not doing OO.

Comment: @sbi in one hand you are claiming against usage of "pseudo-classes" in OO, and on the other hand claiming that working with simple record is also not a OO. this poor entity gets beaten from all angles. So a simple record has no place in programming OO?

Comment: @chook: A record is like a sequence (of code, lines within `{}`) in that respect: Yes, you need it in OO, too, but using it doesn't mean you do OO. (You can use records in Structured Programming as well.) Hiding a structure's implementation behind a compiler firewall strikes me as an odd idea, but I haven't seen a use case to have a chance to think of something else to do instead. But whether it's useful or not in some use case – getters and setters aren't OO. (Why don't you just read the paper I linked to?)

Comment: @ sbi I did read it as you can see I referred to the terms "pseudo-classes" and "quasi-class". Nice paper, however, software engineering isn't a pure science, in some ways more a philosophical field. If you need a record in OO, but it isn't OO, so OO as a concept isn't complete and sound (propositional logic), or alternatively C++ is not a pure OO language. So if a record is needed in OO, why isn't it available in Java, which is considered a more OO language than C++? The paper is too general, and this is not more than a claim, which seems reasonable, but reasonable sometimes isn't enough.

Comment: @sbi As for doing such things in real life, we do it in our company, we need to provide primitive structures for third parties, which are modified constantly. There are ways to avoid setters and getters directly, such as meta objects in QT, but I'm not completely familiar about it.