# Design dilemma deriving multiple classes from base class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm working on some project, and need some simple advice.

I have one base class, and 6 classes derived from that base.

5 of those 6 derived classes should have two private `int`, but the 6th needs just one private `int`. And of course member functions `get()` and `set()` for both ints (6th one just `get()` and `set()` for only one `int`).

My question is: Should I have a base class with two `int`s and `set()` and `get()` functions or should I have a base class with one `int` and `set()` and `get()` for that `int`, and all others derived classes(except the 6th) with one more `int` and two more methods?

Comment: You're presenting your solution for a problem that might be solved in a completely different way. In its current form, this is unanswerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on what do the different classes model and what do the `int` data members mean. Let's assume that your derived classes should really inherit from the base class (and this is a big assumption). I also assume that we are talking about public inheritance here.

For sure, the base class must not contain both `int` data members. If your hierarchy is correct, the second member is only meaningful for some objects of this class (specifically, it is meaningless for objects of your 6th class). Remember that public inheritance models an IS-A relationship: all parts of your base class must also apply to all your derived classes.

Now for the first data member. Does it mean the same in all your derived classes? Will it also mean the same for any other derived class you could conceivably have? Should all objects of your base class have this member? If so, it should appear in the base class.

The most important thing here is to have a good design with correct inheritance. If you have that, then the answer to your questions is trivial. If you don't, the answer is immaterial because you have to fix your design first.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is: Should I have a base class with two `int`s and `set()` and `get()` functions or should I have a base class with one `int` and `set()` and `get()` for that `int`, and all others derived classes(except the 6th) with one more `int` and two more methods?

Assuming public inheritance, this depends solely on your design requirements. Ask yourself: ***Do I need to access that second `int` through a base class reference?*** If the answer to that is *yes*, then it needs to be in that base class. If the answer is *no*, then it shouldn't be in that base class.

I understand the motivation to not to implement that other data several times, but that is an implementation artifact, and should be solved in the implementation (you could *privately* inherit from another base implementing this), rather than in your design.

---

That said, note that, ***if you need setters and getters, [you're doing it wrong](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf)***.

Comment: The linked article does not say that setters and getters are wrong; they are wrong under certain circumstances.

Comment: @Gorpik: I don't know how you manage to read this out of that article.

Comment: It adds the *lack of essential operators and other functions* to the presence of getters and setters for *nearly every member data item*, so that class users are forced to use getters and setters for what should be done with other functions. If they were wrong *per se*, constructs like C# automatic properties would be immediately wrong.

Comment: @Gorpik: Note that the article merely mentions this as indications that you deal with a _quasi class_, not as a must-have. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8456146/140719) for a somewhat extended view of me on getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly shouldn't have redundant methods in your classes. I would suggest creating *7th* class, acting as a base for the other 5:

```
class BaseLevelOne { protected: int X; };
class BaseLevelTwo : public BaseLevelOne { protected: int Y; };

class One : public BaseLevelOne { /* get & set */ };
class Two /* Three, Four, etc. */ : public BaseLevelTwo { };
```

This way you:

- Don't have to write the second `int` five times
- Don't have to have redundant member in class one

If you did actually state what do you want to do with these classes, however, my answer could be perhaps more precise and better suited to the actual use-case.

Comment: @rhalbersma: You mean "...as bad as _public_ data", Shirley?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore eh yes Freudian slip: protected data is as bad as public data